# Is there a System event when processes are created?

Tags: c#, events, process

Is there any event when a new process is created.  I'm writing a c# application that checks for certain processes, but I don't want to write an infinite loop to iterate through all known processes continuously.  Instead, I rather check each process that is created or iterate through all current processes triggered by an event.  Any suggestions?

```
        Process[] pArray;
        while (true)
        {
            pArray = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process p in pArray)
            {
                foreach (String pName in listOfProcesses)  //just a list of process names to search for
                {

                    if (pName.Equals(p.ProcessName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                    {
                       //do some stuff

                    }
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(refreshRate * 1000);
        }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

WMI gives you a means to listen for process creation (and about a million other things).  See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967646/monitor-when-an-exe-is-launched/967668#967668).

```
 void WaitForProcess()
{
    ManagementEventWatcher startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
      new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
    startWatch.EventArrived
                        += new EventArrivedEventHandler(startWatch_EventArrived);
    startWatch.Start();
}

static void startWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Process started: {0}"
                      , e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value);
    if (this is the process I'm interested in)
    {
             startWatch.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Listening for this event requires administrative access. If using Visual Studio, you can simply run Visual Studio as administrator to also debug the application as admin.

Comment: Is there a non elevated solution?

Comment: Non elevated solution to access process creation of elevated processes? This would be a major security risk.

Comment: @AlexandruDicu: It's not really an issue as only an admin can get all the process information.  Look at Task Manager in the Details pane at all a non-admin can see.