# Monitor when a file is in use

Tags: c#, wav, file-monitoring

I need to monitor when a file (*.wav) is being executed.
I know about the filesystemwatcher class. However does this class notify when a file is being used? I also came across [Monitor when an exe is launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967646/monitor-when-an-exe-is-launched). While I realise that this has to do with an exe, is there a way to be notified that a wav file has been executed?

Comment: You could trace whenever a media player is executed. Because a document can not be written within a .docx file. A media player will execute `.wav` format. I think this can fulfill your requirement. If not, comment here and narrow down your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't get an Event when non executable files such as mp3, wav, txt and etc are opened.
But actually can check if file is opened write now...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker())
    {
        bw.DoWork += Bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Press Q to exit");
    while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key!=ConsoleKey.Q){}
}

private static bool[] opened;

private static void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "*.mp3");
    opened = new bool[files.Length];

    while (true)
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            try
            {
                using (var fs = File.Open(files[i], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
                    opened[i] = false;
            }
            catch{ opened[i] = true; }
}
```

P.S. I know it's ugly :D

Comment: Hey it may be ugly but it could be part of a solution