# Windows Service to log every command prompt command each time it loads?

Tags: c#, windows

I have been seeing a random command prompt popup recently it said something like "Cannot find the file path...". and then it closed before I could see what it was and I have Windows updates paused!

I want a log of every cmd load start time, every command run, or at least to tell me what the pid is running in a log. Anything and everything that runs CMD, I want the command that ran logged. Any ideas for a C# Windows Service? Think of this as my own security, I have the right to know what cmds ran on my pc in a list format as they occur. I am a C# developer and found no software monitoring tools online. I think this would be helpful for everyone has the right to know what commands are being run on your pc when, and by whom.

Example found:

```
Process[] processlist1 = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process proc in processlist1){
   Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} ID: {1}", proc.ProcessName, proc.Id);
}
```

This is clearly not enough, it needs to detect when CMD is run by a constant scan or flag of when command prompt is run.

Comment: You can use WMI for that.
See the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967646/monitor-when-an-exe-is-launched/967668#967668) (and vote-up the answer if it is useful to give credit to the author).

Comment: Sounds like you want to hook into the Windows API. For that something like Microsoft Detour should help. And with that hook into all API methods that create processes (CreateProcess, ShellExecutes and all of its variants).

Comment: Thank you for the references Marc and Ralf.
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967646/monitor-when-an-exe-is-launched/967668#967668